# why we specify /mtd /mdd options for visualstudio what is their use?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

HI

i want to know what is use of specifing /mtd /mdd options for visual studio.

Help me in this regard

Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 0):

They both request multithreaded, debug runtime libraries; `mtd` further requests a static link (bigger exe but no dependency on the runtime-library DLL).  See [MSDN's page about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(VS.80).aspx) for more details.